# drop down menu with onclick javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, function, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a drop down menu that calls a JavaScript function when clicked. My drop down menu is like this:

```
<select name = "navyOp"> 
    <option selected = "selected">Select a Navy Op Area</option>
    <option value = "AN01">AN01</option>
    <option value = "AN02">AN02</option>
    <option value = "AN03">AN03</option>
</select>
```

So for each of this options, I want a specific JavaScript function to be called. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach an event listener to select element:

```js
window.test = function(e) {
  if (e.value === 'AN01') {
    console.log(e.value);
  } else if (e.value === 'AN02') {
    console.log(e.value);
  } else if (e.value === 'AN03') {
    console.log(e.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="navyOp" onchange="test(this);">
  <option selected="selected">Select a Navy Op Area</option>
  <option value="AN01">AN01</option>
  <option value="AN02">AN02</option>
  <option value="AN03">AN03</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this always call test()? I want AN01 to call one function, AN02 to call another and AN03 to call another.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

html change or edit:

```
<select name = "navyOp" id = "navyOp">
```

JavaScript:

```
    document.getElementById("navyOp").onchange = function()
{

    if(this.value === "AN01")
    {
        //do this function
        alert("an01");
    }
    else if(this.value == "AN02")
    {
        //do this function
        alert("an02");
    }
    else if(this.value == "AN03")
    {
        alert("an03");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a function that gets called everytime you change the value :

**HTML**

```
<select name = "navyOp" onChange="myFunction()"> 
    <option selected = "selected">Select a Navy Op Area</option>
    <option value = "AN01">AN01</option>
    <option value = "AN02">AN02</option>
    <option value = "AN03">AN03</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
var myDropdown=document.getElementsByName('navyOp')[0];

function myFunction(){
    alert('option changed : '+myDropdown.value);
}
```

#### JS Fiddle

Comment: The drop down menu I have above is only part of it. I also have some values that are AR01A, GL04, etc. So I don't think this would work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is

```
function expand(s)
{
  var td = s;
  var d = td.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0);

  td.className = "menuHover";
  d.className = "menuHover";
}
```

You have to do this for each of your options menu. Hope this answers your question