# Asynchronous search after dropdownlist selection

Tags: jquery, ajax

Currently getting to grips with AJAX and using it to perform database searches.

I'm just wondering if there's a way to automatically begin the search process after selecting something from a dropdown list?

For example, in text boxes you can set:

```
$j("#acc-id-search").keydown(function (event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                searchAcc();
            } 
        })
```

which performs the search upon pressing enter.

Is there a similar thing for performing the search upon clicking on your choice?

[image: Auto Search]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox" onchange="searchAcc();">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Please try this way.
You can call your search function in `dropdown` on change event. This will work definitely. Please have a try.

you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250748/drop-down-menu-with-onclick-javascript-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Well, literally one minute after posting this I tried something and it worked, so here's the solution for anyone who needs it:

```
    <div>
     @Html.DropDownList("product_cd", null, "None", htmlAttributes: new { style = "width: 100%", onclick = "searchAcc()"})
    </div>
```

I used the "onclick" htmlAttribute for the DropDownList. I thought it would be too vague as it isn't specifying the exact part being clicked on each time, but it worked. Happy days, heh.